# how to run native android project by android studio

Tags: android, native

I want to import a native Android project, but it seems ndk-bundle error.
how can I install ndk from the terminal and set ndk path on ubuntu or import project by android studio?

for example, 
how can I import,run and customize this project >>> [Anysoftkeyboard](https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard)

Comment: download ndk from sdk manager of android studio and set the ndk path in your project

Comment: Download ndk bundle from sdk manager, and use "Import project"

Answer (score 1):

download ndk from Setting -> Android SDK -> Select SDK Tools -> Check NDK -> click on ok. The download will start.

[image: Android SDK]

after completion of the download click on Project Structure -> SDK location, you can see ndk path (Android NDK Location), replace this path in your project where it required.

[image]